# Стихотворение "Десять негритят"

Tags: литература

Все мы знаем стишок про десять негритят, благодаря детективу Агаты Кристи. А откуда вообще пошел этот стих и правда ли, что в оригинале были не негритята, а "индейчата"?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем так.          
 Одно время этот роман печатался под названием "И никого не стало" (And Then There Were None). И даже считалочка была переделана. Вместо "Ten Little Niggers" было "Ten Little Soldier".

Песенка-считалочка  написана Фрэнком Грином в конце 60-х годов 19-го века.
Незадолго до ее появления в Англии была опубликована другая песня. Написал ее американец Септимус Уиннер и называлась она Ten little Injuns. Грин же в свою очередь написал подражание песни Уиннера, и она довольно быстро разошлась по мюзик-холлам и прочим подобным увеселительным заведениям.

http://statistic.su/blog/desjat_negritjat_schitalka/2011-02-11-150

По роману А.Кристи написана пьеса "И никого не стало".
Роман экранизировался множество раз. Первой экранизацией стала американская картина «И не осталось никого», снятая в 1945 году Рене Клером. Основным отличием от романа стала концовка, переделанная под хэппи-энд на основе той, что Агата Кристи написала для пьесы, только с одним отличием: Ломбард заранее предлагает Вере фальсифицировать его убийство, после чего Вера намеренно стреляет мимо Ломбарда, так как они стоят за пределами дома и убийца из окна не может услышать о чём они говорили. Последующие ремейки фильма (1965, 1974 и 1989), выходившие под названием «Десять маленьких индейцев/индийцев», использовали ту же самую концовку. Только советский 2-серийный телефильм «Десять негритят» режиссёра Станислава Говорухина (1987) использовал оригинальное название романа и полностью соответствовал сюжетной линии с мрачной концовкой.

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%82